# How do I combine all the layered images for my background?

Tags: javascript, html, css, 2d-games

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S88R5.png)I'm currently trying to build a videogame but the background images that I downloaded on Itch.IO are 3 layered bg images. I don't know how to put all 3 images together to form one in-depth background.

```
**const background = new Sprite({
position: {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
},

imageSrc: './img/background/background_layer_1.png',
```

})**

i've tried adding all three images on one line but it couldn't. I apologize that you can only see one of the 3 images. This posting only allows me to post one image

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure how to help, I see no code here.

Comment: i've updated my post @SteveWalson

Comment: why there is no z ?

Comment: Z? the X and Y are the axis that the image starts on. I don't believe there is a Z within the axis.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Click on layer 1 in your folder, edit in MS paint or 3D paint, or wherever, then insert each subsequent layer onto the first and save.